# How to connect the Rust MongoDB driver with Invalid Tls Certificates?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, rust

I'm **unable to connect to the MongoDB with Tls Allow Invalid Certificate** option with the **Rust driver**.

```
let uri = "MongoDB://user:pwd@host:port/database_name?tls=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true"
let client_options = ClientOptions::parse(uri)?;
let client = Client::with_options(client_options).expect("");
let db = client.database("database_name");
```

I can see that the client_options has correctly parsed the uri with:

```
tls: Some(Enabled(TlsOptions{allow_invalid_certificates: Some(true) ...}))
```

However I get the following non-recoverable error:

```
Error: invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate: UnsupportedCertVersion
```

Server MongoDB: 4.2.18

Client Mongosh: 1.5.0

Rust Driver: 2.3.0

P.s. I'm able to connect to MongoDB by the mongosh shell with the following command:

`mongosh server_dns:server_port/database_name -u username -p --tls --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates`

(It's also possible to connect with described options with pymongo)

Comment: "invalid certificates" are "typically" expired ones or ones signed by a CA not recognized. Here you got "UnsupportedCertVersion", so if it is really a certificate *version* issue you have far bigger problems (as everyone should be using "version 3" certificates long ago): honestly, as much as you may not like it, your time and energy would be better spent fixing that certificate, and for your own security, than trying to circumvent basic TLS features in your code, which lowers security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What solved the issue was to add the feature "openssl-tls" to Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies.mongodb]
version = "2.3.0"
default-features = false
features = ["openssl-tls"]
```

Comment: How and why did that fix the problem `UnsupportedCertVersion`? Also never do this: `--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates`. If you have a broken leg, taking painkillers is not a replacement for setting the bone and casting the leg.

Comment: I don't know exactly why it fixed that issue, but the documentation in states that this feature [https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-rust-driver#all-feature-flags](_Switch TLS connection handling to use 'openssl'_). The MongoDB states clearly that is we should [https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#avoid-use-of---tlsallowinvalidcertificates-option](Avoid Use of --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates Option). I only used in a local environment to test tls connection with MongoDB through the Rust driver and do not intend to use it in production or over the internet.